# Cannot find package error when using go modules inside docker containers

Tags: docker, go

Given I have some experience working with docker containers I decided to use docker containers to have a go environment and learn. Below is my dockerfile for go web app.

```
FROM golang:1.12.0-alpine3.9 as base

ARG GO111MODULE=on

RUN apk update && apk add make bash git

COPY ./app /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app
RUN go build

COPY ./compose/local/golang/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

RUN go get github.com/oxequa/realize

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["realize", "start"]
```

My go.mod file

```
module github.com/rajeshyogeshwar/demoapp

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.6
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.3.0
    github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter v1.2.0
    github.com/lib/pq v1.0.0
    github.com/spf13/cobra v0.0.3
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.2.0
)
```

and finally my project folder structure

[image]

As we can see I am trying to use httprouter module and it has been defined in my go.mod file. But I keep getting following error.

```
app_1        | [06:46:56][APP] : Install 
app_1        |  main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" in any of:
app_1        |  /usr/local/go/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (from $GOROOT)
app_1        |  /go/src/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter (from $GOPATH)
```

So if anyone can point out the obvious mistake it would be great.

Comment: How do you run your app (not `realize start`)? Anyway, maybe try to use `go install` instead of `go build`, and then just use the built binary directly.

Comment: @YuryFedorov I tried install, but the error persists. As for running the app, I am running a simple server and listening on port 8080

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar Is this `Install` error from `entrypoint.sh` file? Could you show its content? `ARG` value in Dockerfile is only set/available on build, after that it is removed, you probably should set `environment` value

Comment: @ttomalak I realised it few minutes back and have set GO111MODULE as environment module. As for entrypoint.sh there isn't anything in it as of now.

Comment: @ttomalak that was precisely the issue. Because the ARG in my Dockerfile only set the variable during build stage, go build or go mod download command would not work. As per your suggestion and my realisation I updated it and it has worked. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: @Rajesh Yogeshwar should I put it as answer to your question then?

Comment: Sorry mate, your answer was partially correct. The problem still persisted as my app directory was within GOPATH and the GO111MODULE was getting set to auto even after passing it as environment variable. It worked for me because I had manually executed export GO111MODULE within the container. I am still trying to solve this question. You were partially correct though and hence an upvote to your comment.

Comment: Did you changed your `ARG GO111MODULE=on` to `ENV  GO111MODULE=on` and rebuilded image(Dockerfile)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189882/discussion-between-rajesh-yogeshwar-and-ttomalak).